# Control which element should have focus() next when tab is pressed from an input field

Tags: jquery, css, knockout.js

I have a list of elements on a page, some of which are inputs, other anchors, etc etc.  When I'm on an input, I want to tell the browser which input tab should push the focus to if I hit tab.

Right now one of my inputs is pushing me to a menu item when I hit tab; I want it to go to the next input.  I'm looking for a general approach here as I have no clue where to start.

The number and names of my input fields are dynamic as well.

I'm using knockout in case it's relevant.

Comment: Why not just use the tabindex attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set `tabindex` attribute on html

[Example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EmP5n/)

```
<input type="text" tabindex="1" />
<input type="text" tabindex="4" />
<input type="text" tabindex="3" />
<input type="text" tabindex="2" />
```

Answer (score 1):

To supplement @BrunoLM's answer, you could use `tabindex` with `attr`  binding if you're going dynamic, like when you want to control the effect of `tab` key on inputs.

```
<input type="text" data-bind="attr :{'tabindex' : dynamicNumber "}" />    

<a data-bind="attr: { href: url, title: details }">Report </a>

<input type="text" data-bind="attr :{'tabindex' : dynamicNumber "}" />
```